# What is meant by "Singular rejection"

Tags: word-meaning

What is meant by **"Singular rejection"**?

This combination is used by a news anchor while describing the defeat of a leader.
He used the following sentence:

> "The leader received a singular rejection, as under his leadership, his political party received electoral defeats in a number of states."

As per this usage, **it appeared that by "Singular rejection" he meant "total rejection"**.

However, when I checked the meaning of *"Singular"* at [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/singular) or at [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/singular), I didn't find any meaning of *"singular"* matching this context. I also searched at [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=singular%20rejection&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csingular%20rejection%3B%2Cc0) and I found that this combination is used a lot, but I didn't find any definition of this combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have missed it but in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/singular)

> **singular** adj
>
> [FORMAL] of an unusual quality or standard; **noticeable**:

Being noticeable a synonymn of **notable** that according to Google Translator is

> worthy of attention or notice; remarkable.

Maybe you can not assure that it was a total rejection but it was remarkable one.

Answer (score 3):

Check this one:

> [**singular**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/singular) *adj*
>   3. a. Being beyond what is ordinary, especially in being exceptionally good; remarkable: *"Dinners with [our two friends] became the evenings we looked forward to with singular pleasure"* (David Halberstam).
>   b. Strange or unusual: *"I accordingly obeyed forthwith what I still considered a very singular summons"* (Edgar Allan Poe).